# Publish content from a subsite to the parent

Tags: 2013, publishing-site, content-query-web-part, sub-site

I'm trying to work out if I can publish page content from a subsite upto the parent site.

I want departments to have their own subsite where the manager can enter what's happening on the department home page and have that automatically appear on a page in the parent site.

I've tried CQWP but I could only get a link to the subsite page, not the content of the page.

I'm using on-premise 2013 Enterprise

Comment: what kind of pages your trying to publish and what you want see on top level site....link to the subsite page or complete page etc?

Comment: The content of the subsite page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Site Columns and a Site Content Type for the information the manager is entering. (Perhaps, just use Announcements.) Then provision a list in each subsite using that content type.

In the root site, use [Content Search Web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163789.aspx) to surface the list entries.

Comment: Thanks Paul. So do I use CSWP and build a custom design template to show the content? I've tried remapping the properties but I can't find the column 'Body' used in the announcement content type in the list.

Comment: Sorry I should add I tried remapping the properties from the OOB web part config panel. I've not tried modifying anything using visual studio or the likes.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Content Search Web Part was what I needed, using that and a custom design template has allowed me to achieve my goal.

I was able to use the Page content type on the subsite, specifically the Welcome Page - default.aspx and republish that content to the parent site in a format that suited the need.

Thanks again.

Scott